Convert large Int values into 2 byte unicode characters
I'm working on a library, currently supporting, "net47, net48, net6.0, net8.0, netstandard2.0, netstandard2.1" to extend and create an easier way to use 256 color, font style, and special characters within Console apps.
I currently have an Enum with Unicode as the name and the integer value.
Example:
U2797 = 10135

This is easily converted to a 1 byte character as a string.
// could be '\u2797' or in this case "➗"
var charVal = $"{(char)10135}";

However, my issue is with 2 byte special characters.
Example:
U0001F435 = 128053
// Result needed: "\ud83d\udc35" or "".

I've attempted:
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(128053)
var uResult = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
var aResult = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytes);

Neither of these results have what I'm looking for.  I've been searching for the last 3 days digging around different possibly solutions and still I have no solution.
Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

What's wrong with writing "\u2797" and "\U0001F435"?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf32?view=net-8.0

@KlausGütter, I created these in enums, because they are also used for parameters passed into methods, therefore I can't use "\U0001F435" as an emum value.  Also, I can't create single quoted version '\U0001F435' on the fly.  Converting from a large int would be the only way i can think of doing it.

@HansPassant, That works..   var doubleByteChar = char.ConvertFromUtf32(128018).ToString()    Please post it as the answer, I'll accept..
